`Could not find the '@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server' builder's node package` while installing `single-spa-angular` module in angular 16
I want to create micro frontend architecture for angular app.For this I'm using single-spa module.Now after adding single-spa-angular library using ng add single-spa-angular command,I'm getting Error: Could not find the '@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server' builder's node package. while running the project.
I'm using angular 16.
Attaching my angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "app1",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            },
            "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4200/"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "none"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "outputHashing": "none"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

package.json :
{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:single-spa:app1": "ng build app1 --configuration production",
    "serve:single-spa:app1": "ng s --project app1 --disable-host-check --port 4200 --live-reload false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "single-spa": ">=4.0.0",
    "single-spa-angular": "^9.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "16.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}

How to solve the issue?
